# Meteor Call Server Method in Client Got 404 Method Not Found Error

Tags: meteor

I am new to meteor and running to an issue trying to call a server method on the client.

```
// Client code 
Template.email.events({  
 'click #test-button' : function(e, t) {      
    Meteor.call('testMethod', function(err, response){
      if (err) {
        alert("error: "+ err)
      } else{
        alert("success")
      }
    });        
 }
})

// server code
if (Meteor.isServer) {

  Meteor.methods({
    testMethod: function () {
       return "success";
    }
  });
}
```

When I click on the button, I got a Error: Method Not Found 404. I tried to put the server method inside Meteor.startup and still gets the same error.What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like your code is only running on the client side. Move the block inside the `if (Meteor.isServer)` to a javascript file in the `/server` directory of your project.

Code inside the `/client` directory wont run on the server at all, so `Meteor.isServer` would always be `false` and the method would never get created on neither the client or server

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It works when I move the code to the server folder. However, what is the point of the Meteor.isServer then?

Comment: Its for distinguishing where you run your code if you put it in the root directory (runs on both the server and client). Sometimes you might want to share the same code but have little tweaks between the server and client. But its not too advisable as the copy of the server side code would be sent to the client, but it wouldn't run.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `Meteor.methods({...})` out of `Meteor.isServer()` then Meteor will detect you methods.

Answer (score 0):

Plus put the methods on server side (server root folder), I notice that the alphabetical names its important to load three calls method.
I had the same problem when I had the next structure

```
server
  |----- dht-setup.js
  |----- methods.js
```

Then, dht-setup dont see the methods.js methods. Instead, I change the name of the file:

```
server
  |---- _methods.js
  |---- dht-sensor.js
```

The 404 Not found, fixed. The same issue I found in client side when a want to separate functions from templates, for example, separating D3js functions from the templates. You probably need ensure top of the alphabetical load using "underscore" character "_".
Consider that, cause the examples work fine cause the methods are defined in STARTUP.JS, at leat alphabetical word.